# Unable to receive Location updated from OnlocationChanged

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Unable To Receive updates from OnLocationChanged snippet  code from Developers Google I am reciveing only getlastknown location later that the Interval is not working unable to add UpdateLocationRequest

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class FusedLocationWithSettingsDialog extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {



    private Button btn_location;
    private TextView txt_location;
    protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
    protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;


    protected TextView tv_pincode, tv_city;


    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 10;

    private static final long MIN_TIME = 2000;
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 10;

    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 500;

    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;



    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    protected LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;

    protected Location mCurrentLocation;



    protected String mLatitudeLabel;
    protected String mLongitudeLabel;
    protected String mLastUpdateTimeLabel;

    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    protected String mLastUpdateTime;


    int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fused_location);
        btn_location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_detect_fused_location);
        txt_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeTextView);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeTextView);
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLastUpdateTimeTextView);
        tv_city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
        tv_pincode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pincode);
        mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
        mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
        mLastUpdateTimeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.last_update_time_label);
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        createLocationRequest();

        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
        btn_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                checkLocationSettings();
            }
        });

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();


        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);


        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }



    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }



    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }


    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            goAndDetectLocation();
        }

    }

    public void goAndDetectLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            }
        });
    }


    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    goAndDetectLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            startLocationUpdates();
            updateLocationUI();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateLocationUI();
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
                LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {


        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }



    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");

                Toast.makeText(FusedLocationWithSettingsDialog.this, "Location is already on.", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");

                try {

                    Toast.makeText(FusedLocationWithSettingsDialog.this, "Location dialog will be open", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    status.startResolutionForResult(FusedLocationWithSettingsDialog.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }



    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                    mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                    mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(String.format("%s: %s", mLastUpdateTimeLabel,
                    mLastUpdateTime));

            updateCityAndPincode(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }




    private void updateCityAndPincode(double latitude, double longitude) {
        try {
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(FusedLocationWithSettingsDialog.this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                tv_city.setText("City=" + addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                tv_pincode.setText("Pincode=" + addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());
                //  System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_detect_fused_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detect location"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mLatitudeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mLongitudeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mLastUpdateTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pincode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting question. :)

Comment: New to asking , Will check Thanks

Comment: You can check in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) on how to request Location Updates. It's stated here that before requesting location updates, your app must connect to location services and make a location request. This documentation shows you how to get the update using the LocationListener callback approach. Call `requestLocationUpdates()`, passing it your instance of the GoogleApiClient, the LocationRequest object, and a LocationListener. Define a `startLocationUpdates()` method, called from the `onConnected()` callback.